# What is an Accessible Word?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles. I'm pretty sure this hasn't been done already.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule I call it an Accessible Word™.  Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Accessible Words™ | Not Accessible Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| PINK | MAGENTA |
| WATER | JUICE |
| MILK | CHEESE |
| FACETS | NUANCE |
| KILL | MURDER |
| JUMP | LEAP |
| FEARED | FRIGHTENED |
| DEGRADE | INSULT |
| WARS | BATTLES |
| HUMP | CAMEL |
| EDWARD | ALPHONSE |

CSV version:

```
Accessible Words™,Not Accessible Words™
PINK,MAGENTA
WATER,JUICE
MILK,CHEESE
FACETS,NUANCE
KILL,MURDER
JUMP,LEAP
FEARED,FRIGHTENED
DEGRADE,INSULT
WARS,BATTLES
HUMP,CAMEL
EDWARD, ALPHONSE
```

What makes a word Accessible? Explain the title of the word group in your answer too.

Comment: I had the same idea, but being lazy doesn't help much.

Comment: @rhsquared what does being lazy have to do with anything?

Comment: Oh, but it does. I was lazy and never got to post this question.

Comment: @rhsquared well, it gave me a chance to dip my toes into the puzzling.se sommunity so I thank your laziness! But oh, the wonderful puzzles that must've been lost to the laziness of people far smarter than I...

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, although it is really similar...

Comment: Fixed the duplicate to the *correct* duplicate. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An Accessible Word™ is

> a word which can be written with one hand on a QWERTY keyboard with standard finger placement (index fingers on F and J).

They're called "accessible" because

> they can be easily accessed with one hand?

Comment: Got a quick access...

Comment: As it happens, I have one in front of me right now! What a coincidence, right?

Comment: Wow, that was really quick! Any idea why they're called Accessible?

Comment: Yeah, that's right! I'll probably wait a bit before accepting your answer but consider the green tick in the bag